# How to assign name of variable to a file name?

Tags: r

I have a object `period` which will be the current month id.
Now, I have different files with the suffix of period and I want R to read and work on those files at many places in a program.

Example

```
Period="202105"

file 1=SG202105
file 2=MN202105
```

How can a create a object `period` and call it at various places in the program?

Comment: You want to create just the year/month string `"202105"`?

Comment: I think you need `paste`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `Period` object as `pattern` argument in `list.files` to get names of the files that has that value in it.

```
Period="202105"
list.files(pattern = Period)
```

Comment: No I mean I have a  script and in that at various places want r to read the object and use it

Comment: Example at 1 place I  want to read a csv SG202005 and in another place i want to create a data frame MP202005 so I want to know how to use this suffix if I only specify it at the begin of the script and call it at various places

Answer (score 0):

To create an object with the current year and moth in the format `yyyymm`, use this function. It accepts any R object of classes `"Date"` or `"POSIXt"`.

```
new_period <- function(date = Sys.Date()){
  d <- format(date, "%Y%m")
  d
}

Period <- new_period()
Period
#[1] "202105"
```

Comment: No I mean I have a script and in that at various places want r to read the object and use it Example at 1 place I want to read a csv SG202005 and in another place i want to create a data frame MP202005 so I want to know how to use this suffix if I only specify it at the begin of the script and call it at various places

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `paste0` and `assign`, try this example:

```
Period = "202105"
file1 <- paste0("SG", Period, ".csv")
file2 <- paste0("MN", Period)

# read file
myFile <- read.csv(file1)

# create a data.frame
assign("file2", data.frame(x = 1, y = 2))

ls()
# [1] "file1"  "file2"  "myFile", "Period"
```

Comment: I tried paste but the issue is when we read.csv it will look for file name file1 and say that file1 does not exist

Comment: @rprogrammer then please edit your question and clarify more.